# Unable to load local images in onsen.ui 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, hybrid-mobile-app, monaca, photoeditorsdk

I have created a Monaca app with Onsen.ui2 framework in which i am using the PhotoEditorSDK library from ng2-photo-editor
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-photo-editor.

In the PhotoEidtComponenet.ts(say in my case) file I need to specify the absolute path of its assets folder.
Please check the attached images for my project view hierarchy.

I tried with different path like "../../utlis/PhotoEditorSdk/assets" etc.,
but the icons inside the assets does not get load.

It is assets: {  baseUrl: './assets' } where i need to specify the absolute path.

Below is my code how i am trying to load integrate the library

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, EventEmitter, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
const PhotoEditorSDK = require('../../utils/PhotoEditorSDK/js/PhotoEditorSDK.js');
const PhotoEditorReactUI = require('../../utils/PhotoEditorSDK/js/PhotoEditorReactUI.js');
const UnsplashProvider = require('../../utils/PhotoEditorSDK/js/UnsplashProvider.js');

@Component({
      selector: 'ons-page[page]',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    template: `
        <div #host id="photo-host" style="min-height: 100px; min-width:100px"></div>
        <img src = "app/img/test.jpg">
        <div class="actions">
                 <a class="btn white-btn active" (click)="cancelClick()">Discard</a>
            <a class="btn white-btn pull-right" (click)="saveClick()">Save</a>
          </div>`,
        styles: [require('../../utils/PhotoEditorSDK/css/PhotoEditorReactUI.css') ]

})

export class PhotoEdit{

  @ViewChild('host') host: any;
  el: ElementRef;
  editor: any;
  propagateChange = (_: any) => { };


  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
      this.el = el;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      // this.createEditor();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.createEditor(), 1);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.editor) {
          this.editor.dispose();
      }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
  //        console.log(changes);
      if (this.editor) {
          this.editor.dispose();
      }
      this.createEditor();
      this.propagateChange(changes);
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
      //console.log(value);
  //        if (this.editor) {
  //            if (value && value !== '') {

  //            }
  //        }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
      this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) { }

  createEditor() {
      let myImage = new Image();
      myImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      myImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
          this.editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
              container: this.host.nativeElement,
              logLevel: 'info',
            title: '',
            showTopBar: false,
            showCloseButton: false,
            editor: {
                image: myImage
            },
            photoRoll: {
                provider: UnsplashProvider
            },
            assets: {
                baseUrl: './assets'

            },
            ui: {
                enabled: true,
                showExportButton: true,
                export: {
                    type: PhotoEditorSDK.RenderType.DATAURL,
                    download: false
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            language: 'en'
          });
      myImage.src = "./test.jpg";
  }

  saveClick() {
      this.editor.export(false)
          .then(result => {
              // this.saveImageEvent.emit(result);
          });
  }

  cancelClick() {
      // this.cancelEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

I tried to load a simple image in

Any help is appreciate. 
Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeKP9.png) in advance

Comment: If you are using CLI you have to add the assets path to the 'assets' section in .angular-cli.json to tell the server to deliver the files.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I am using Monaca CLI to run the project command like "monaca preview" which with webpack host the server for my application.
I can't find any file name angular-cli.json in my project

Comment: Sorry, I talked about Angular CLI. About Monaca CLI I do not know anything.